# Create Entity with another entity's Id but without relation between

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some entities:

```
class Cat
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Dog
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Log
{
    public long EntityId {get;set;} // cat Id, or dog Id
    public int EntityType {get;set;} //cat or dog
    public string Payload {get;set;} //some information
}
```

I want to create new `Log` entry for every insert and update action.
It's easy to do it in update statement, when I have cat or dog Id.

```
var cat = GetCatFromDb();
//cat.Id != 0
UpdateCat(cat);
DbContext.Set<Log>().Add(new Log {EntityId = cat.Id, EntityType = 1});
```

But's it's difficult to create new Log entry when I insert new `Cat` or `Dog` object, because, they don't have relation with `Cat` and `Log`.

```
var cat = new Cat{Name = "Kitty"};
//cat.Id == 0
DbContext.Set<Log>().Add(new Log {EntityId = cat.Id, EntityType = 1});
```

But I don't want to add navigation property to `Cat`, `Dog` or `Log` class because Log table is a system table and have no relation to "bussines" objects.

My example is simlyfied, I have may objects, and I can change many of them in many places in one transaction. So, I want to log all of them.
Is there any way to get this? Maybe using `DbContext` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the new cat, save changes and then use the cat `Id`:

```
var db = new YourContext();
var cat= new Cat(){Name="New Cat"};
db.Set<Cat>().Add(cat);
db.SaveChanges();

// Here it will use inserted cat Id
// MessageBox.Show(cat.Id.ToString());
db.Set<Log>().Add(new Log {EntityId = cat.Id, EntityType = 1});
```

Comment: Yes, I can. My example is simlyfied, I have may objects, and I can change many of them in many places in one transaction. So, I need to find all of them, call SaveChanges, get Id's and call SaveChanges again for Log.

Comment: Yes, you should do that to find new inserted Ids.

Comment: @Backs Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it helpful:)

Comment: I checked some cases and now I can say: yes, it's acceptable

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)